# Interfacing with C/C++ routine in C# causes rip

Tags: c#, dll, pinvoke, dllimport, interopservices

I have a vendor's API call, which I want to use in my C# [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application. The problem is that no matter what [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) I try, I get a crash on the line stating that the call has unbalanced the stack. I tried working with the vendor, but they do not have Visual Studio 2012 nor have any experience with C# or [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) and after several back and forth emails, they basically washed their hands of the problem.

Here is their official C/C++ declaration

```
const char *<dll name here>(int Param1,
                            const char *Param2,
                            const char *Param3,
                            unsigned long Param4,
                            unsigned short Param5,
                            unsigned short Param6,
                            unsigned short Param7,
                            unsigned short Param8,
                            unsigned short Param9);
```

Here is a recent P/Invoke DLLImport line that I tried.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport(
    "<dll name here>", EntryPoint = "<AnsiFunctionName>", ExactSpelling = true,
    CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern String <AnsiFunctionName>(int Param1,
                                               String Param2,
                                               String Param3,
                                               ulong Param4,
                                               Int16 Param5,
                                               Int16 Param6,
                                               Int16 Param7,
                                               Int16 Param8,
                                               Int16 Param9);
```

Here is the actual error message:

> Subject Line: PInvokeStackImbalance was detected
>
> A call to P/Invoke function '' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the P/Invoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

I tried various things, even putting a void return type. I tried not using the return type. I tried instead of Strings, StringBuilders and IntPtrs. No matter what I tried, nothing works.

I mentioned to the vendor after reading an article here on Stack Overflow that returning a string is dangerous and should never be done. Their response was:

> *"The string return problems mentioned on that page don't apply to
> our functions. They return a pointer to a statically-allocated string, so you don't need to free it (and must not try to do so). It looks like the "UnmanagedType.LPStr" should work (though the IntPtr thing should work too, with the proper conversions or casting).*

Update #1: As mentioned in the comment, I was using uint, not ulong, up until this post. I just thought that I make the comparison look better. Both uint and ulong do not work.

Update #2: Maybe giving the actual function name will help. It is Armadillo CreateCodeShort3A. Going forward, I am using pure .NET, but I do still need to interface to that, just it is not really possible at the moment. More than that, the problem got me curious why I cannot resolve something seemingly so simple as a P/Invoke. After all, how many variations are there? (not a serious question).

Comment: This is probably not the main problem, but "unsigned long" in C++ would normally be equivalent to "uint" in C#, not "ulong". (Similarly, "long" in C++ is usually "int" in C#).  On the other hand, "unsigned long long" would be equivalent to "ulong" in C#.

Comment: Up until this post, I was using uint, not ulong, just for writing this question I changed it to ulong, which also fails.  I tried a zillion, or at least, quite a few permutations, so far nothing works.

Comment: You forgot the calling convention - you need `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl` as part of the DllImport, otherwise it uses the StdCall calling convention, which is incorrect and leads to this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the possibilities that I can see:

1. The return value should not be `String`. Use `IntPtr` and convert to a string with `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi`.
2. The C++ type `unsigned long` should be matched with `uint`. You used `ulong` in C# which is a 64-bit type. In C++ on Windows, `unsigned long` is an unsigned 32-bit type.
3. The C++ type `unsigned short` should be matched with `ushort`.
4. The calling convention used by the C++ DLL is probably `cdecl`. Add `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl` to your [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services).
5. Don't use `SetLastError` for such a function. That's used with Win32 API functions that return error conditions through `GetLastError`. This DLL file almost certainly does not.

So the P/Invoke should look something like this:

```
[DllImport(@"mydll.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr FunctionName(
    int Param1, 
    string Param2, 
    string Param3, 
    uint Param4, 
    ushort Param5, 
    ushort Param6, 
    ushort Param7, 
    ushort Param8, 
    ushort Param9
);
```

Comment: The problem was the missing CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl.  I have been hitting my head against the wall on this for days now.  I also found out that the function must return an IntPtr but can accept a string as an argument.  Works great and I was right.  The solution was something simple and stupid that I just did not see.  Thanks to both Petesh  and David.  I also implemented David's other comments and works great too.  I did not known/realize that SetLastError was for Win32 API. I am not sure the difference between UInt16 and ushort, but I made that as well.  Thanks.

Comment: There is not different between `UInt16` and `ushort`, but in your question you have `Int16`.

Comment: change from `CallingConvention.StdCall` to  `CallingConvention.Cdecl` works for me